# asp listitem Value property

Tags: asp.net

Thanks SOF, here I come with another asp.net question.

in my asp dropdownlist control, I use appenddatabounditems feature to bound to an asp listitem

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CMListDD" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="CMListDD_ODS" >
           <asp:ListItem value="" Text="Select a CM"/>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

I searched MSDN, and think the .net should render this to html

```
<option value="">Select a Product</option>
```

In my code behind, I have a objectdatasource bound to my gridview to return a table based on the selected value from my dropdownlist. I use string.IsNullOrEmpty to catch this empty value, but somehow, the function doesnt catch this empty value.

```
 public DataTable GetPRList(string CM)
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CM))
                {
                   return null;
                }
                else
    {
    // do sth
    }
}
```

The if clause does not catch the empty string, but go the else{}. Anyone has any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should provide some code also.

Comment: You need to edit your question to provide more details to make it clearer

Comment: Sorry, somehow my codes didnt get pasted..

Comment: how is CM passed? I think you should post all relevant codes

Comment: I always use "Select" as the text and then "%" as the value. What is your sql statement that uses the dropdown selection as the variable?

Comment: The problem is not related my sql statement for sure, because when i change <asp:ListItem value="empty" Text="Select a CM"/>, and my if clause to  if( CM=="empty") it works fine...

Comment: Thanks briskovich, any value other than empty string is fine. I am just wondering why the empty value can not be validated by string.isnullorempty method.. maybe value="" doesnt actually get rendered as empty string?

Comment: If you have a a sql statement " Select * where x like @param " and your param is "" it won't work. If your param is "%" it will. You see what I mean? There is no need to verify an empty string in the code behind logic at all. You either pass a value or the wildcard.

Comment: Hi briskovich, I know what you mean. FYI, the GetPRList is a method bound to my gridview not my dropdownlist. I add a listitem to dd and set the value to "", so supposely, my method should validate if the autopostback value from dropdown is "".

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdownlist looks like this, it should work

```
<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server"
    Appenddatabounditems="true">

   <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="-- Select a Product --"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

Note: I set the `Value=""`